# Problem with locating Raw Data with DataRun NTFS

Tags: ntfs, ntfs-mft

I have an image of a NTFS file which contains multiple test file. When i get to a windows Bin i encounter the data runs :
1 cluster => 4096 / 0x1000 bytes

22 BD 00 42 01 21 56 67 FF 11 03 97 11 13 D7 00.

Normally it would means that i have 4 runs :

22 BD 00 42 01 => 0xBD clusters @ 0x142 cluster offset

21 56 67 FF => 0x56 clusters @ 0xFF67 cluster offset

11 03 97 => 0x3 clusters @ 0x97 cluster offset

11 13 D7 => 0x13 clusters @ 0xD7 cluster offset

The problem is, there is not enough clusters to attain 0xFF67, you get out of bound.

The raw data found in the 3 clusters at 0x97 offset dont match any data in the file either.

Anyone knows what the problem might be ?

Here the code for the whole entry it starts at the offset 0x14400

```
46 49 4C 45 30 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 01 00 38 00 01 00 B0 01 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 41 00 00 00 5B 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 48 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 30 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 C3 CD AA 79 E0 48 D6 01 00 A6 A1 73 74 AE D4 01 4F DA 03 E7 40 60 D6 01 AA B7 DF 77 40 60 D6 01 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 30 00 00 00 70 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 00 58 00 00 00 18 00 01 00 05 00 00 00 00 00 05 00 C3 CD AA 79 E0 48 D6 01 00 A6 A1 73 74 AE D4 01 B0 33 8A E4 40 60 D6 01 AA B7 DF 77 40 60 D6 01 00 90 12 00 00 00 00 00 F8 83 12 00 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0B 00 74 00 65 00 73 00 74 00 42 00 49 00 4E 00 2E 00 62 00 69 00 6E 00 50 00 00 00 68 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 50 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 01 00 04 80 14 00 00 00 24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 34 00 00 00 01 02 00 00 00 00 00 05 20 00 00 00 20 02 00 00 01 02 00 00 00 00 00 05 20 00 00 00 20 02 00 00 02 00 1C 00 01 00 00 00 00 03 14 00 FF 01 1F 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 80 00 00 00 50 00 00 00 01 00 40 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 28 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 12 00 00 00 00 00 F8 83 12 00 00 00 00 00 F8 83 12 00 00 00 00 00 22 BD 00 42 01 21 56 67 FF 11 03 97 11 13 D7 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 03 14 00 FF 01 1F 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 80 00 00 00 50 00 00 00 01 00 40 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 28 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 12 00 00 00 00 00 F8 83 12 00 00 00 5B 02 F8 83 12 00 00 00 00 00 22 BD 00 42 01 21 56 67 FF 11 03 97 11 13 D7 00 FF FF FF FF
```

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact the answer was fairly simple. Every offset are signed 8bits, 16bits or 32bits depending of the size in bytes given. Note this is one of the few emplacements with signed numbers in the system hex.

FF67 => 1111111101100111 = > -153 / - 0x99 => 0x142 - 0x99 = 0xA9 as the offset for the second data run.